# Get the name of hyperlink clicked from previous page-FLASK

Tags: python, html, flask

I am creating a project on examination.

In my first html page I have a set of hyperlinks which represent the name of question papers. The question papers are stored in the form of tables in MySQL.

What I want is,to return the name of the hyperlink clicked by the user in my python code.

All the links should lead to the same webpage,but the contents in each link is different.

This is my python code for the webpage which should open after one of the links is clicked:

```
@app.route('/qsetdisplay/exam',methods=['GET','POST'])
def exam():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'answer' in request.form:
            
            cursor5 = db3.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            tablename = request.args.get('type')
           
            print(tablename)
            cursor5.execute("select questions from {}".format(tablename))
            
            cursor5.execute("select answers from {}".format(tablename))
           
            cursor5.execute("select marks from {}".format(tablename))
            print("ques:", ques)
            print("ans:", ans)
            print("marks:",marks)

    return render_template('exam.html',ques=ques,marks=marks,ans=ans)
```

tablename returns as none in the above code.

This is my html code for the webpage which would open after oneof the links is clicked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EXAMINATION</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form name="ex" id="ex" action="{{url_for('exam')}}" method=POST>
        <h1 align="centre">ALL THE BEST!!!</h1>
        {% for que in ques %}
        <h6>{{que}}</h6>
        <textarea name="answer" id="answer" placeholder="enter answer"  rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br><br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input name="sub" id="sub" type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the html code for the previous page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>STUDENT PROFILE</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="/">
         <h1>"WELCOME STUDENT"</h1>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <form name="QD" action="{{url_for('qset_display')}}" method="get">
        <input name="QD" value="CLICK TO VIEW QUES PAPERS" type="submit"><br><br><br><br>
        <h1>THESE ARE THE AVAILABLE PAPERS:</h1>
        {% for name in names %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('exam', type=name) }}">{{name}}</a><br><br>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I correct my code?

Comment: you have to somehow put the text of `name` (URL escaped) in the URL, as part of the path or as argument (after the `?`)

Comment: How to do it sir?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building